# TabBar in IPhone foursquare app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitabbar, foursquare

There is an interesting feature in the Foursquare App's TabBar

[image: TabBar]

The central button in this app is bigger than others.
Can i realize it with standard xcode TabBar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's the guide](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/) how to create such tabbar button.